# Cannot upgrade windows 10 home to pro using retail product key

Tags: windows, windows-10, upgrade, windows-10-upgrade

I bought a new laptop with pre-installed windows 10 home.

I have Windows 10 Pro product key on another laptop, so I detached and copy product key from the old laptop.

When I try to activate the windows 10 pro product key on my new laptop I got information that activation has been successfully processed but I still have Windows 10 home.

I did everything exactly like in this article https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/upgrade-windows-10-home-to-windows-10-pro-ef34d520-e73f-3198-c525-d1a218cc2818

Section Upgrade using a Windows 10 Pro product key

Do you have any idea how to upgrade Windows 10 Home to Pro using retail product key?

Comment: Did you actually buy the product key on the old machine, or was it simply ready to go when you got it? [99/100 ready-to-go computers have a non-transferrable OEM key]

Comment: Yes, i did. As I wrote it is Windows 10 Pro retail product key

Comment: @MaciejSkuratowski - I assume you have performed a reboot of the machine? Using [ShowKeyPlus](https://github.com/Superfly-Inc/ShowKeyPlus/releases) is the retail key detected?